How can I configure my iPhone so that it rings if my Apple AirTag gets less than 1 kilometer away from my phone?
I've linked an Apple AirTag with my iPhone (i.e., I see the AirTag in the "Find My" app). The AirTag is currently in some bag far away, but it will get back to my place soon. How can I configure my phone so that it rings if the AirTag gets less than 1 kilometer away from my phone?

You could set an automation to do so.
Go to the Shortcuts app, click "Set Personal Automation", click "NFC", and scan your AirTag.
Try to set the "less than 1 km" alert as it is or as close as possible if there is nothing similar to what you need.

How did you configure your AirTag to register as an NFC device?

@nohillside Seems AirTags are supported like that. Can't find any relevant docs on Apple support, but found this page https://www.howtogeek.com/729280/how-to-use-an-airtag-to-trigger-nfc-shortcut-automations/ I can't verify as my phone is too old (X supports NFC, but not with Shortcuts) and I have no AirTags!

Correction, there is a reference to NFC in the Shortcuts user guide starting in iOS14, but re supported devices it only states "Note: Not all devices support NFC.", nothing specific.

@AndyGriffiths I tried with an AirTag of mine, couldn’t make it work. Let‘s hope the OP comes back to clarify.

@nohillside Yes, while Shortcuts has some NFC support, it is by no means clear if the answer fulfils the question.

Thanks, I tried with 2 AirTags (1 bought in 2024, 1 bought in 2023), neither  of them couldn't connect to Shortcuts via NFC. There is no NFC tag on the AirTags so I am not sure whether these AirTags have NFC. Tested with iPhone 12 mini and iOS 15.

Apple Toolbox says to open the shortcuts app. If you don't have it, you can download it from the app store. Next, tap "Automations at the bottom, select Create Personal Automation. Choose NFC or near field communication as the trigger. Hold the AirTag near your phone and follow the instructions. Lastly, configure it to trigger when the tag is less than 1 kilometer away.

Why isn’t this an edit to the other answer?

This one actually cites the source and this one is less vague.

It’s fine to post mostly the same answer as another, but an edit can add the source more elegantly than multiple answers with mostly the same words. It’s a super contribution to link to a source so thanks so much for that. Just wanted to comment in case people vote on seeing the text repeated.

You are correct that the other answer needs a citation, so I’ve dropped that hint to the world :)
